# SVN shows a file as conflicted while merging even though the file is same in both branch

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

We are merging trunk to a branch using Tortoise SVN.
We selected merge a range of revision with empty box. (default it will merge all revisions)

In Trunk one file was modified in revision r100 and then later this file was again modified in revision r200 (In r200 the file was made same as branch code).

When merging first it tries to merge revisions r90 to r110 and it gives merge conflict.

How can we avoid this issue so that SVN only tries to merge the latest version of the file?

If we give only the latest revision number while doing the merge, then files which were modified in that revision only gets merged.

[image: TortoiseSVN showing merge conflict]

Note: Below is the actual latest SVN revisions

branch : r49175

trunk : r49176

Comment: Merge conflicts can have different reasons and TortoiseSVN does a pretty good job providing details (esp. the latest version). Can you please include that information in the question?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Added few more details and a Screenshot

Comment: To see the conflict information you need to [launch the *Edit Conflict* dialogue](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html). My preferred way is to launch "SVN Check for modifications" from context menu and then select "Edit" on the affected item.

Comment: Yeah! we opened the merge conflict editor and the line which was showing as conflicted should not be conflicted ideally. Because in the latest revision the file has been made the same in both the branches.
Like this, we get conflict in lot of files which are now same. This is happening because SVN is trying to merge the older revisions first.

Comment: Perhaps I've badly misunderstood the question. You can't merge "latest version" of a file. You don't merge files, you merge *changes* to files. TortoiseSVN offers some nice "canned responses" to handle common merge conflicts but you don't seem to be getting them so I guess your version is not current.

Comment: a hint: C H A R A C T E R  E N C O D I N G

Comment: @bahrep can you please elaborate your comment?

Comment: @rishi the files in the repository and your working copy can have different line endings and character encoding.